# Saxon CE 1.1 - Using result-document to create a output file

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I've been playing with Saxon-CE_1.1 over the last few days and have managed to create a little application that allows users to classify pictures according to a data dictionary using a select dialog.  All was going really well until I tried to use the `result-document()` function in it's "classic" way, to create a new file in the file system containing the choices the user has made.

XML Quire is returing with a severe error stating:

> XpathException in mode: '{http:saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT}onclick' event: [object MouseEvent]: Expected '?select=' ir '#' at start of result document href found "filename.xml

This error seems, to me, to be stating that I must pipe the results back into the HTML using # or ?select/

Is it still possible to create "external" output using SaxonCE? If so how can I accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

Until recently it has not been possible to read or write files in the local client machine from Javascript code running in the browser, and if Javascript can't do it, then Saxon-CE can't do it either.

This may change soon with the HTML5 FileSystem API, but as far as I'm aware support for this is still very patchy. When it appears to be more stable and widespread, we can certainly look at implementing both doc() and xsl:result-document to access local filestore (or indeed, implementing the EXPath file module).